# DefineProperty object in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, typescript2.0, angular2-nativescript

Is there any way to use defineProperty on Object.prototype in Nativescript? I'm trying to define the method "IsObject" but, when I add the function, the app crashes.

The function is:

```
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "IsObject", {
        value: function ()
        {
            let obj: Object = this;
            return obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object';
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that you are trying to do this in NativeScript, why would you define an Object method, and then use it to report whether it isn't null, and is of type object... I would rethink the necessity of such a function

Comment: @pkanev I'm not going to discuss with you why, because I'm trying to migrate a webapp to nativescript, and sometimes there are a lot of questions that you can do about that (specially when the code isn't 'your' ou 'mine'), but you're right, It doesn't make sense. 
Ignore it because I have a lot of another methods like "Is", "ToArray", ... to migrate. Can you go back to the main question?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this on Android; and had no issues adding your code.   I made a couple minor changes:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "isObject", {
        value: function ()
        {
            var obj = this;
            return obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object';
        }
 });

// To Test, I put in a tap handler
var x = {};   console.log("IsObject?:", x.isObject());
```

I lower-cased the isObject (since that is the proper format for items).
I also removed the un-need TS specific code; no need to make the TS compiler do anything to this function...

P.S. I'm with Peter, modifying the Object prototype can be dangerous...